# What is the benefit of Shimano Click'R technology?

Tags: pedals, clipless, pedals-clipless

Im looking into making the switch from platforms to clip-less and just saw SPD pedals with "Click'R" technology ( [Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D85K5OA) ) Im not sure if its worth the extra money to buy that opposed to SPD pedals without the "Click'r" Technology.

**Has anyone tried both?**

**What do you think?**

This will also be my first ever pair of clip-less pedals so i prefer something beginner friendly which is what the "click'r" advertises

Just found this from the Shimano Website a great video Describing their Click'R Technology [Youtube](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D85K5OA)

Their Website also has a great Diagram

http://www.shimano-lifestylegear.com/us/fw/technologies/clickr.php

Comment: From what I heard, it's easier to click out and click in than normal SPD pedals.

Comment: @EricSmekens Do you know if the ease is that much more than regular? and if its worth it ?

Comment: If you're interested, I would probably try to find a bike that stocked them and see if they have a way to let you try them out. From what I understand, they are easier to clip into and out of. Based on the link from @FocusedMuffin, about 60% easier to clip into and out of.  It's already pretty easy to clip into and out of SPD to begin with.  You'd probably be better off trying it for yourself then trying to gauge the feel of the pedal from what people wrote on the internet.

Comment: @FocusedMuffin No, I don't have experience with it.

Comment: One thing that might be worth considering is that Click'R appears to be a new system, and Shimano have 2 established clipping systems already. What is the possibility that in a year or two they will designate this third system a failure, and leave users high and dry? Bear in mind that every cyclist in the world who wears clipless pedals has gone through the process of learning to use them, so it can't be too difficult.

Comment: @Kibbee Thanks for that information, That regular clipless pedals are already easy to clip in and out of, I Ended up picking up a pair of [link](http://www.amazon.com/Shimano-PD-A530-Dual-Platform-Pedal/dp/B001MZ2AGO/ref=sr_1_5?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1432213379&sr=1-5&keywords=clipless+pedals)
From craig's list for $30 My shoes should be arriving on Friday ! Im pumped to try them out. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option to that new system is the existing SPD system with the ["Multi-Directional" cleat (SM-SH56)](http://www.shimano-lifestylegear.com/us/fw/products/accessory/cleat.php?pSccleat002).  This cleat just makes the step-in and release a little easier than the standard cleat (no numbers on it).

The advantage (over the Click'R) is that it's using the tried-and-true SPD system, and when you get comfortable with that cleat, you can replace it with the standard cleat for a more secure connection.

The cleat may not be as recessed as the Click'R, but with standard MTB shoes there's usually enough shoe tread around the cleat to provide normal walking (I've never had a problem slipping on my cleat).

Comment: Thanks for the Help! I ended up getting regular shimano spd pedals and getting the Click'R shoes so I could walk around campus comfortably. I started off with the single directional release cleat and it wasn't too bad... until i fell haha -_-. 

so I upgraded to the SH56 cleats and oh my goodness World of difference!. The downside is its not recommended for bunny hopping  because they may unclip. These cleats have saved me from unclipping accidents more than once.

Comment: @FocusedMuffin Glad to hear you found a solution.  Note: a properly executed bunny-hop does not use your feet to pull the bike up - see any of the trials bikers who ride with flats.

Comment: Oh Really? Any tips or resources on how to learn to bunny hop properly on a road bike?

Comment: @FocusedMuffin It's no different than on a BMX/MTB... You've probably seen those videos where guys on road bikes do trials... they're usually using flat pedals.  Resources for bunny hopping abound: http://www.mtbtips.com/how-to-bunny-hop/ and http://www.leelikesbikes.com/turn-my-bunny-hops-into-rabbit-hops.html are two.

Answer (score 6):

The Click'R system allows for a more recessed cleat in the shoe. It is a very similar design to Shimano SPD but is marketed for commuters and trekkers who want dual purpose shoes for when they are on and off the bike.

They also allow for multi-release meaning they offer a wider range of movement to release the cleat from the pedal making them easier to use.